# Count positive values in column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table  with multiple columns of numbers. I'm trying to get stats for this table and I'm stuck trying to count the amount of positive increases between rows in a single column.

what I have

```
A  |  B  |  C
--------------
1  |  5  |  2
5  |  2  |  7
2  |  2  |  10
18 |  0  |  14
```

function I'm trying to write for my problem

```
def countIncreace(data,value):  #not complete but what I have so far
  print( data[value].pct_change().fillna(0).count( > 0) )
```

`pct_change()` returns a table of the percentage of the number at that index compared to the number in row before it and `fillna(0)` replaces the `NaN` in position 0 of the chart that `pct_change()` creates with 0

my desired output:

```
[IN]>countIncreace(df, 'A'):
[OUT]> 2
[IN]>countIncreace(df, 'B'):
[OUT]> 0
[IN]>countIncreace(df, 'C'):
[OUT]> 3
```

What am I missing to in my function to get the count of positive values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close! Everything is correct except for the way you are trying to count the number of percent changes greater than 0. Here is one way of doing it

```
def countIncrease(df,column):
    print sum(df[column].pct_change().fillna(0) > 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.Series` methods `gt` (greater than) and `sum`:

```
df[column].pct_change().fillna(0).gt(0).sum()
```

In general, this is a better idea than using built-in functions with Pandas series / NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
len(df.loc[df.A > 0]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, (3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print(len(df.loc[df.A > 0]))
```

Or just `[` `]`:

```
print(len(df[df.A > 0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use query , its a little more easy to read.

```
len(df.query('A > 0'))
```